# Create a tuple of lists from a list

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

Is there a way to create a tuple of lists from a list comprehension?

Something like:

```
actual_clients_emails, actual_client_names = [partner.email, partner.name for partner in op_client.ResPartner.browse([])]
```

I want to create 2 lists form one list.

I can do it this way:

```
actual_clients_emails = [partner.email for partner in op_client.ResPartner.browse([])]
actual_client_names = [partner.name for partner in op_client.ResPartner.browse([])]
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You currently have a list of `(email, name)` tuples - what do you want? A tuple of a list of emails and a list of names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply done using [the `zip()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
actual_clients_emails, actual_client_names = zip(
    *[(partner.email, partner.name)
      for partner in op_client.ResPartner.browse([])])
```

Comment: @maazza Really? The only thing I can think of is if you are using 3.x, the tuple needs to have brackets in the list comp (I have changed my answer to reflect this), but that existed in your code, so I presumed you were in 2.x. If that isn't it, please post your whole error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
client_names = tuple([partner.email, partner.name for partner in op_client.ResPartner.browse([])])
```

Comment: This would be a tuple of tuples, and I'm not sure if this is actually what the OP is after.

Comment: On re-reading the question I think you're quite right. I thought the OP was trying to make a tuple from a list comprehension. I'll wait for clarification on the question then edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, the original question was incredibly unclear, but I think it's clear now.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer and will just leave mine as it is, since you've already given the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I like elegant one line code, but in this case I'd prefer to split this up, for clarity:

```
partners = op_client.ResPartner.browse([]) # get the partners list
actual_clients_emails = [p.email for p in partners]
actual_client_names = [p.name for p in partners]
```

This should work fine if "partners" is a list.

If otherwise it is a generator, you should not ask it twice to generate your sequence of partners. In that case this code should prove better:

```
partners = op_client.ResPartner.browse([]) # get the partners generator
mail_name_generator = ((p.email, p.name) for p in partners) # generator for your info
email, names = zip(*mail_name_generator) # unpack it
```

this second solution is, IMO, less readable and therefor worse. It's more pythonic though, and more versatile.